# tikz stops drawing into pdf after 20 line segments in plot generated through knitr tikzDevice

Tags: tikz-pgf, texstudio, r, knitr, tikzdevice

## Problem

If I try to draw a curve generated through `knitr` using `tikzDevice` into `.pdf` only 20 line segments of that curve are drawn and `TeXstudio`, through which I do it, just leaves message

```
running command '"C:\PROGRA~2\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe" "plot2-1.tikz"' had status 1
```

so I tried to look to `/figure` folder where I found a `.log` file where was a line mentioned on which the drawing ended and it was exactly 20 points after the first point of that curve. After that it had the same errors until the end of the file. These errors look like this:

```
Missing character: There is no X in font nullfont!
```

where `X` was the character in the `.tikz` file which it should have read and drawn.

## Example

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\begin{document}
<<plot, dev = 'tikz', echo = FALSE, cache = FALSE, fig.width = 7, fig.height = 5>>=
   curve(sin, 0, 2*pi)
@
\end{document}
```

If I omit the `dev = 'tikz'` in chunk options, it works. I've also tried many other things which had no effect on this issue so I deduce there's something wrong with `tikzDevice` package in `R`.

my `tikzDevice` has version 0.7.0

## Question

What should I do to have my curves drawn complete?